# Allowed Patterns in cloud Formation templates

Tags: json, aws-cloudformation

```
"AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
```

Can anybody explain this? Please

Answer (score 0):

It means:

- `(\\d{1,3})`: 1-3 digits
- `\\.`: Dot
- `(\\d{1,3})`: 1-3 digits
- `\\.`: Dot
- `(\\d{1,3})`: 1-3 digits
- `\\.`: Dot
- `(\\d{1,3})`: 1-3 digits
- `/`: Slash
- `(\\d{1,2})`: 1-2 digits

This looks to be a [CIDR Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_range), such as: `54.142.11.0/24`

It is using Regular Expression (Regex) notation, with some extra backslashes to escape backslashes.